# Ensure prize pool doesn't award tied participants less than participants who scored worse

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine, math

If I had $1000(variable) and I want to split that amount up and give it to 20(variable) people, but rather than give it evenly to each person, I want to give more to the 1st person, and the 2nd person, etc.

So the 20th person gets the least, and the 5th person gets the 5th most.

People are sorted into a list by score, how could i check to make sure people with the same score are awarded the same amount of the prize while still giving out the prize total to all people?

Formula thus far:

```
int people = 20;
float prize = 1000;

List<int> list = new List<int>();

for( int i = 0; i < people; ++i )
{
    list.add(Random.Range(0,100));
}

list.Sort();

float k = (2 * prize) / ((people) * (people - 1));
float sum = 0;

for (int i = 1; i < list.Count-1; ++i)
{
    var personsPrize = i * k;
    sum += personsPrize;
    Console.WriteLine(personsPrize);
}
Console.WriteLine("sum = " + sum);
```

First place would get 25% of the total prize pool. Second place gets 20% and third place gets 15% then the rest is divided between the remaining people, with people on the same score getting the same amount.

What should happen for people getting tied first equal? They shouldn't get less than anybody else, but shouldn't double the first prize value.

Comment: i think the algorithm would depend on how much the prize should vary, i.e. does first place get twice second place or a 2nd place value + 10 or 10% more

Comment: First place would get 25% of the total prize pool. Second place gets 20% and third place gets 15% then the rest is divided between the remaining people, with people on the same score getting the same amount.

Comment: and what if there are two tired for first? they split the 25% or they each get 25%?

Comment: You'd expect them to share both 1st and second place amounts ((25% + 20%) /2), which would leave 3rd and subsequent places unaltered. Cypras is however defining the rules here.

Comment: I'm not sure how best to handle that, because if 4 tied for first, that's the whole prize pool. But if we split it, they might end up with less than lower placed users.

Comment: There are still holes in the specification. What if there are fewer than 6 people? 4th will get more than 1st if there are only 4, and more than 2nd if there are 5.

Comment: There will be a minimum of 20 people

Comment: This isn't a duplicate because the first question was about a loop bug and this one is about ensuring that the occurrence of ties do not violate that each lower scoring participant should receive less prize than any single higher scoring participant.

Comment: @Cypras remember me, from the original question? I have an answer for this question, not joking about it, but I cant provide it because is marked as duplicate. Recommend changing the title of the question to something "Prize pool allocation in progression" so it can be reopened, because people (not boots) search based on title on stack overflow any matches but they don't read the question!

Comment: @SilentTremor Good idea, I went ahead and changed the title

Comment: How can I mark it as not duplicate?

Comment: I'll put another answer on original.

Comment: You can close this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it by splitting out the prize fractions first, and determining which prizes should be merged due to ties. Then, sum up the merged fractions and divide that merged amount equally to all the tied participants.

This ensures that the amount received for each tied participant is less than or equal to the greatest prize amount merged in and greater than or equal to the least prize amount merged in.

```
   public class Person
   {
      public Person(string name, int position)
      {
         Name = name;
         Position = position;
      }
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public int Position { get; set; }
   }

      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         var winners = new Person[]
         {
            new Person("Test 1", 1),
            new Person("Test 2", 1),
            new Person("Test 3", 1),
            new Person("Test 4", 1),
            new Person("Test 5", 5),
            new Person("Test 6", 6),
            new Person("Test 7", 7),
            new Person("Test 8", 8),
            new Person("Test 9", 9),
            new Person("Test 10", 9),
            new Person("Test 11", 11),
            new Person("Test 12", 11),
            new Person("Test 13", 13),
            new Person("Test 14", 14),
            new Person("Test 15", 15),
            new Person("Test 16", 16),
            new Person("Test 17", 17),
            new Person("Test 18", 18),
            new Person("Test 19", 19),
            new Person("Test 20", 19)
         };

         var prizes = SplitPrizeFund(1000, winners.Length);
         AllocatePrizes(winners, prizes);
      }

      private static void AllocatePrizes(IEnumerable<Person> positions, double[] prizes)
      {
         var orderedPositions = positions.OrderBy(f => f.Position).ToArray();

         for (var pos = 0; pos < orderedPositions.Length;)
         {
            var currentPerson = orderedPositions[pos];
            // Find equally placed people (if any)
            var comList = orderedPositions.Skip(pos).Where(f => f.Position == currentPerson.Position).ToList();

            // We should now have one or more people in our list
            var splitWays = comList.Count;

            // Total the prize fund over the places found
            double splitFund = prizes.Skip(pos).Take(splitWays).Sum();

            // Allocate the total winnings equally between winners of this place
            bool first = true;
            foreach (var person in comList)
            {
               if (first)
               {
                  Console.WriteLine($"{person.Name,-20} {(splitFund / splitWays),10:C2}");
                  first = false;
               }
               else
               {
                  // Identify equal placed winners 
                  Console.WriteLine($"{person.Name,-19}= {(splitFund / splitWays),10:C2}");
               }
            }

            pos += splitWays;
         }
      }

      private static double[] SplitPrizeFund(double totalFund, int numberOfPrizes)
      {
         var prizes = new double[numberOfPrizes];
         var remainingFund = totalFund;
         int remainingPrizes = numberOfPrizes;

         // Special handling for top three places
         int pos = 0;
         prizes[pos] = Math.Round(remainingFund * 0.25, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
         pos += 1;
         prizes[pos] = Math.Round(remainingFund * 0.20, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
         pos += 1;
         prizes[pos] = Math.Round(remainingFund * 0.15, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
         pos += 1;
         remainingPrizes -= 3;
         remainingFund -= prizes[0] + prizes[1] + prizes[2];

         // Linear reducing split from 4th (replace this with whatever you want)
         int totalPortions = 0;
         for (int i = 1; i <= remainingPrizes; i++)
            totalPortions += i;

         for (int i = remainingPrizes; i >= 1; i--)
         {
            prizes[pos] = Math.Round(remainingFund * i / totalPortions, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
            remainingFund -= prizes[pos];
            totalPortions -= i;
            pos++;
         }

         return prizes;
      }
```

Comment: I didn't realize what you were saying at first which is why I originally downvoted this answer. I think someone else may have done the same. Hopefully I helped make things a bit clearer about why this is a good solution.

Comment: Steve, this is great, but it doesn't work for 4-5 people. If you have a prize pool of $20, and 4 people, it gives everyone $5, that's not exactly right. Same for 3 people, each get $4 which doesn't total the prize pool amount.

Comment: @Cypras, I asked the OP about this, and he said there would not be less than 20 people. It was his choice over the split for places 1-3. If you need it for less than 6 people then modify the SplitPrizeFund function.

Comment: @Cypras, I see you were the OP. The same point applies. Your own rules about the split for the top 3 places cause the problem. You could take out the special handling section in SplitPrizeFund, letting the function generate a simple linear reducing amount for each place.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a solution :

```
class People
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Rank { get; set; }
    public float? Prize { get; set; }
}
```

//Reserves 60% of the prize for the first, second and the third person.
//Imageine that there are 5 people have the highest rank 20 for exemple.
in this case the total of the first place makes 125%. It can't be possible.

For me, you should have another parameter to choose the first places.

Or, you should modify your rank logic: like if the total of percentages is over 100% or 90%, (or a percentage that you will decide), reduce the percentage of the first place, second and third places etc.

Imagene that you have 4 first place, 1 second place and 1 thirt place.

In this case you have (4 * 25%) + 20% + 15%  = 135%. It means you have to reduce your 25% to for exemple 15 %, second place to 10% and the third place to 5%.

in this case you will have (4 * 15%) + 10% + 5% = 75 percent for your highest places and you will distribute 25% to other users.

```
    private void CheckPrices()
    {
        float prize = 1000;
        Random rnd = new Random(1);
        var peopleList = new List<People>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            peopleList.Add(new Test.People() { ID = i + 1, Rank = rnd.Next(5, 100) });
        }


        var firstPrize = prize * 25 / 100;
        var secondPrize = prize * 20 / 100;
        var thirstPrize = prize * 15 / 100;

        int i = 0;
        //Sets first places prizes.
        foreach (var person in peopleList.OrderByDescending(ro => ro.Rank))
        {
            i++;
            if (i == 1)
                person.Prize = firstPrize;
            else if (i == 2)
                person.Prize = secondPrize;
            else if (i == 3)
                person.Prize = thirstPrize;
            else
                break;
        }


        var totalRank = peopleList.Sum(ro => ro.Rank);
        float prizePerRank = (prize - (firstPrize + secondPrize + thirstPrize)) / totalRank;

        foreach (var person in peopleList.Where( ro=> ro.Prize == null))
        {
            person.Prize = person.Rank * prizePerRank;
        }

        //
        var totalPrizeDistributed = peopleList.Sum(ro => ro.Prize); //= 1000
    }
}
```

Comment: We don't yet know how the OP want to arrange the prize hierarchy. How can you offer a solution when the problem is not properly defined?

Comment: The problem is clear for me, he/she wants to distribute prizes depending on the rank of the user. More an user have points, more the user earns. I don't see why we can't understand the problem.

Comment: Will this give users with the same score the same prize while keeping the total prize pool the same? Looks like it will.

Comment: Yes.But, I should modify my code in order to keep the percentages for first 3 places.

Comment: Is there a way to separate the top 3 ranks and give them 25,20,15 percent of the total prize pool and then cycle down the remaining prize pool to the rest of the people?

Comment: Steve Todd, downvoting for only downvoting is not usefull.

Comment: Yes, I modify my code, I am going to publish a modification.

Comment: How will the code handle multiple first place winners if they happened to have the same score?

Comment: That's a real smart way to handle the first second and third places, do you think you could show that in your code on how you'd handle that? Learning a lot from you!

Comment: I am going to try to modify my code.